# gfortran Error: Function 'inint' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using `gfortran` (from gcc-4.8.1) to compile a `.f90` source file, and encountered an error that says:

```
Error: Function 'inint' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I did a bit of search and found that a [GNU website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/INInt-Intrinsic.html) says [`ININT`]

> This intrinsic is not yet implemented. The name is, however, reserved
>   as an intrinsic.

In a [SGI documentation](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&raw=1&fname=/usr/share/catman/p_man/cat3/ftn/round.z), it is said

> ININT returns the nearest INTEGER*2 to its REAL*4 argument.

My questions are:

Is `ININT` a Fortran77/90/95/2003 standard function?

In `gfortran`, what's the proper/standard-compliant way of writing a replacement function for `INIT`?

Comment: It definitely is not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used `ININT` before, and it probably is not of any standard. Instead, I would recommend to use [`NINT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NINT.html#NINT) (FORTRAN 77), which takes an optional `KIND` argument (Fortran 90):

```
RESULT = NINT(A [, KIND])
```

(Taken from [`the GCC docs`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NINT.html#NINT))

Choose `KIND` to reflect `INTEGER*2`, whatever that is for your specific compiler... But while you're at it, try [`SELECTED_INT_KIND`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fINT_005fKIND.html#SELECTED_005fINT_005fKIND).

Comment: +1 Thanks, I used NINT() w/o the kind, and it seems OK so far.